# Creating QPixmaps in a thread

Tags: python, pyqt, multiprocessing, pyqt5, python-multiprocessing

I have a problem where I am trying to load a whole lot of png images and subsequently display theme using PyQt. My current workflow is to use a multiprocessor pool to map a function which opens each file with 'rb' values, then reads the bytes of each file into a unified list. Finally the parent process then displays the image by calling the `fromImageData` method of a QPixmap object. This method seems to work fine, but is quite slow to redraw a new pixmap each time I switch between images (8K resolution).

I was hoping that it may be faster to instead create a pixmap for each image and cycle through the pixmap rather than recreating the same pixmap with a new image at each step. To do this, I tried to create a pixmap in the multiprocess function, however this is not allowed because there is no parent QApp in the thread.

My question is if there is a proper way to do this? I have alsp thought of doing it with celery/reddis, but i cannot see that having any different ourcome. Is creating a new pixmap for each image and switching them using `setPixmap` is even a viable option or are there more appropriate ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a `QThreadPool` and some `QRunnable`s which wrap the code that loads the pixmaps. Something like:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui

class PixmapLoader(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        super().__init__()
        self.filename = filename
    def run(self):
        # Load pixmap at filename 
        # ...
        # then emit in a signal
        loaded.emit(pixmap)

    loaded = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QPixmap)
```

Then somewhere in the main application, create a thread-pool, run the loading objects, and handle their signals.

```
pool = QtCore.QThreadPool()
loaders = [PixmapLoader(filename) for filename in filenames]
for loader in loaders:
    loader.loaded.connect(handle_new_pixmap)
    pool.start(loader)

def handle_new_pixmap(QtGui.QPixmap):
   # do stuff with pixmap
```

*I've not tried this*, but because Qt is handling the threading, this should be able to take advantage of multiple threads just fine.

**EDIT**

As explained in the comments, this won't work. I've forgotten that `QRunnable` doesn't inherit `QObject`, and that `QPixmaps` cannot be created outside the main thread. But it's pretty straightforward to instead use an image loader object, move it to one or more background threads, in which it loads a `QImage`, and then sends that to the main thread for later use. Here's tested code that will do the bare-bones, loading all PNG files in the current directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

class ImageLoader(QObject):
    loaded = pyqtSignal(str, QImage)

    def __init__(self, filename):
        super().__init__()
        self.filename = filename

    def on_load_signal(self):
        img = QImage(self.filename)
        self.loaded.emit(self.filename, img)   


class LoaderManager(QObject):
    request_img_load = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.loaders = list(map(ImageLoader, 
                filter(lambda f: f.endswith('.png'), os.listdir())))
        self.bg_thread = QThread()

        for loader in self.loaders:
            self.request_img_load.connect(loader.on_load_signal)
            loader.loaded.connect(self.handle_img_loaded)
            loader.moveToThread(self.bg_thread)

        self.bg_thread.start()

    def __del__(self):
        self.bg_thread.quit()

    def load_all(self):
        self.request_img_load.emit()

    def handle_img_loaded(self, name, img):
        print('File {} of size {} loaded'.format(name, img.byteCount()))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication([])
    manager = LoaderManager()
    manager.load_all()
```

Comment: This code will not work. Qt does not support creating pixmaps outside the main thread, so you need to use `QImage` instead. Also, `QRunnable` does not inherit `QObject`, so it cannot emit signals. You should use `QThread`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it's 100% correct. I would however like to warn everyone that pixmaps take up a huge amount of memory!

Comment: This is a good example, but there is basically no point to it because it still freezes the main thread due to the python GIL... A method using multiprocessing would be needed for any practical benefit.

Comment: @spencer Qt threads are not Python threads, and are not subject to the GIL.

Comment: @bnaecker you sure about that? If that's true it would be huge, but from experience I don't think that is the case.